# MySQL: Altering table to add composite key with foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have the following two tables

```
Table: User    
Columns: id, name, age

Table: Task
Columns:  id, task_name, user_id, friend_id
```

`user_id` is the foreign key from the `User` table.

I need to write a query to alter a table that creates a `composite` index between `user_id` and `friend_id`.

Is the command below a right approach:

```
ALTER TABLE Task ADD CONSTRAINT compsite_key PRIMARY KEY (user_id, friend_id)
```

The goal is to make sure that there is never a duplicate of `user_id` AND `friend_id` record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a composite *index* by using `create index`:

```
create index idx_task_userid_friendid on task(user_id, friend_id);
```

You can also do this using `create table`/`alter table` with the `key` or `index` keywords.  But this is the more typical way of creating an index.

Comment: The following command seem to run fine: `create index idx_task_userid_friend_id on task (user_id, friend_id);`

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE Task ADD PRIMARY KEY (user_id, friend_id)
```

Comment: I am getting an error:  `Multiple primary key defined`

Comment: The primary key in the `Task` table right now is `id`

Comment: ALTER TABLE Task DROP PRIMARY KEY;    then the code above. you have to drop the current PK first.

Comment: Can you please add some more context around your answer. Code-only or link-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and  future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: @Alex I am getting the following error: `Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`

Comment: ohh little detail you left out, you have an auto_increment on the table and that always has to be the KEY, so put a unique index on it:

ALTER TABLE `Task` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `name` (`user_id`, `friend_id`);